# Composing curried functions

Tags: scala, currying

I'm in the following situation. I would like a function to only be able to run in a given context. At the same time I would love to be able to compose these functions using the `andThen` syntax (It would just look much better in this case).

So here is a small example for a worksheet. I would love to be able to do it the second way.

```
implicit val iInt: Int = 2

def a(a: String)(implicit ctx: Int): String = a
def b(b: String)(implicit ctx: Int): String = b

val works = b(a("foo"))
val fails = a("foo") andThen b
```

The general question would probably be. How does one compose curried functions? But if somebody can meet the requirements described in the first paragraph I would also be interested.

Comment: Seems to be more related to PartialFunctions than currying. Otherwise wouldn't your signature look something like `def a(a: String)(b: String)` and then you'd use both variables in that same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line works as you want with your definitions of a and b:

```
val worksToo = (a _ andThen b) ("foo")
```

a and b are transformed to functions (because there are not), then chained.

Comment: Yeah. Just got it myself. Is there any chance to remove the underscores? Maybe by using some implicit conversion. Btw. the second underscore is redundant.

Comment: yes you are right, i edit the code to remove the second '_'

Comment: I think this could be done better given some constraining information about the function in question and using implicit conversions to write a dsl. But I'm accepting this for now and will come back to this later

Comment: @Lukasz: If you want to get rid of the underscores, the easiest way would be to use functions. You talk about functions in your question, but you never use a function, you only use methods. The underscore is to convert a method into a function. It would be much easier to just use functions in the first place.